# transition density of discrete time stochastic process with continuous state space

Tags: stochastic-processes, continuity

I have a stochastic process with continuous state space with state variable $z \in [0, 5]$; the state transition is governed by a random variable $x \sim U[0, 10]$ (uniform distributed) and next period's state $z_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}x$, which is independent of $z_n$. Then the transition density is $p(z_{n+1}|z_n)=f_x(2z_{n+1})=\frac{1}{10}$. Watch out the transition density, if this is right, we have the total probability from any $z_n$ in transition to the whole state space is $\int_0^5 p(z_{n+1}|z_n)dz_{n+1}=\int_0^5 f_x(2z_{n+1})dz_{n+1}=\int_0^5 \frac{1}{10}dz_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}<1$. This is very weird since the total probability any $z_n$ in transition to the whole state space is actually $\int_0^{10} f_x(x)dx=1$.

In general the state transition is a mapping from a uniform distribution with support $[0, 10]$ to another distribution with support $[0, 5]$. Intuitively the transition density should be $p(z_{n+1}|z_n)=\frac{1}{5}$ such that $\int_0^5 p(z_{n+1}|z_n)dz_{n+1}=1$ since the new distribution should be more dense than the original one.

The problem may lie in the transition density. I have been stuck here for some time and I was wondering whether you guys could help me out. Any comments are appreciated!

Comment: I don't follow your description of the process.  Is there just one random variable $x$, or a whole sequence of them?  As written it appears that the process goes to the point $\frac{1}{2} x$ and then stays there indefinitely.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! Yes there is only one random $x$ governing the process. The next state $z_{n+1}$ is half of the realization of $x$, e.g., $x=4$ with density $f_x(4)$, then $z_{n+1}=2$ with density $f_x(4)$. Since the state space is $[0, 5]$ and $x \in [0, 10]$, all the state in $[0, 5]$ can be visited from time to time. The question is starting from any $z_{n}$, the transition probability to the whole state space is supposed to be 1, instead of being $\frac{1}{2}$ as demonstrated above...